# Typescript: access object prop type in another prop of this object

Tags: typescript

I have a renderer function for list item, that takes a config object as first argument. Object contains optional ID of list item to render, and should pass this exact ID to onClick handler.

I want typescript to validate this as much as possible (so inside onClick handler ID type should perfectly match the ID passed in config object).

Here is a code that works exactly as I expect it should work, with several testcases (here is [a link to sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMglgZ2ASWBAtgBQE4HswIA8yAIlBAB5oB2AJglEtnNQOYA+1ArugEYTZ2XOhABmLCLQB8UALxQA3gCgoqqHFoB+AFxRSAbhVrc1AMIAbOAGMA1roAUG3aQCUcmQDdcGwwF8lAaLCVsBwJlDYECLY8EioGMRklDT0jMDMbJw8-ILCtGIStHJQeQXUklL2ymrqtAA0RqomFtY2Sr66sShoWHgEiVJu1WpWJkhQlsW0uFY8UcAAdFaRAIZoAKLmGPP2AOSWuy6GNZYLK7S06x7zXVECe1aWtrt1UPZusjLDNU1mTzaOIorBiufRQAD04KgAAlcAB3KDAXBQFZeDSIgAWaygACJgTi0mtttRgCi6FAbBAIGAUeZzIiIOMrMDGVAwMCEJpGlBfC5uZFgFxsNQJnA-AElJC5LIZbK5fKFYqlUrJVCACqM0nMhCM7Sqt466CjdDoeYMFjkFZWDEMpksqBwuDAG0sUS4bDoNZhEUrXi4LikyiQEKScjYPDYBB8qXK2Nx+OygJSjV2nVQACMunRwKg3D4AiUkWiXXi6Cq3KcGYaNWa-wcGg+X25NQ0Syx2AAgsB7AAGI4QqEIDH+8xFIfwsMR3Q4fACUBQXbWlad4C7KDTVnUXCBiiIUnhUCQBfp3YLZtqVtIgBicAokneYKl464o9z28Yw4RK2oIEn7u5-i8km6qalA2rQAATFmQIMEwLCsIWUT5DEe6luWLa0LouxwWwAD6GgvNytatPWtCNoo56qJeuA3netAPgOH4jmOn5-tg059HOv67Net6SGuG4MFuO57lAB7gNAuw4jhrD4bQOKnlAJDoiA-pQKa34LuIdG7FyPwXrQbbLl2vb9k+w4vkUwlMV+P5sQB7R8vqKZavaADM0HkBQYBPE65i-jqpI5qU4jlLQiHFqhPToQZughYU1bGH8JFvA27gUfpVGGbxdEMeZzE2WxugAPK8AAVhAITqAwYC4AgCBwLw-kLvFYW7JRtRGSupmPoOFmvuOCICFOUClRVVWIGydUNU13GtfxDlAc5oHgVAAAsnmTdZgURchJbRd8YnJbYpHkYdGELDl95mX1BWDUVo3lZVpKTbV9WNc1uzzbQ7WZZ1S7dX2vVMZZhXDe6JVPRNNXTR9c0iKFC01IBTnJit9oAKyeYe0CvRyoY5qwdzMFYiISa8vABm+ehkI6zqYtiONsngHgaJIu0CPtCQyZUCiMc+r7OngtkPTOkDYPOuwEdV6mIA1bDqCKTMLCrUBNSsavmBr6tEcddipWR6XnWoUqjCS8xiaImKTcydK8FaNjrrgjLUDx6kQMAaDYFAbre86k1oKmECLS4QA) with this code):

```js
type ListItemProps<ID extends string|number|undefined> = {
    id?: ID;
    onClick: (id: ID) => void;
}


function renderListItem<ID extends string|number|undefined = undefined>({
    id,
    onClick
}: ListItemProps<ID>) {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.addEventListener('click', () => {
        onClick(id as ID); // How to avoid that "as" statement and keep all test cases pass?
    })
    return li;
}


// =============================================
// Test cases:
// (see comments in each test case with information about expected errors)
// =============================================

// Test case 1: id as number
renderListItem({
    id: 1,
    onClick: (id) => {
        id.charAt(0); // should show error: Property 'charAt' does not exist on type '1'.
        id.toFixed(); // should not show any error
    }
})

// Test case 2: id as string
renderListItem({
    id: 'string_id',
    onClick: (id) => {
        id.toFixed(); // should show error: Property 'toFixed' does not exist on type '"string_id"'. Did you mean 'fixed'?
        id.charAt(0); // should not show any error
    }
})

// Test case 3: id explicitly set as undefined
renderListItem({
    id: undefined,
    onClick: (id) => {
        id.toFixed(); // should show error: Object is possibly 'undefined'
        id.charAt(0); // should show error: Object is possibly 'undefined'
    }
})

// Test case 4: id is not set
renderListItem({
    onClick: (id) => {
        id.toFixed(); // should show error: Object is possibly 'undefined'
        id.charAt(0); // should show error: Object is possibly 'undefined'
    }
})

// Test case 5: id type is passed as generic type, but no ID with that type provided
renderListItem<string>({ // should throw an error: Property 'id' is missing in type ... bla bla bla
    onClick: (id) => {
        // content of this callback doesn't metter for this test case
    }
})
```

Despite this code almost works as expected (except test case #5), I used a hack, that I don't much like - inside `renderListItem` function I used `id as ID` statement.

**So, my question is** - how can I avoid using `as ID` inside `renderListItem` and keep all this test cases work exactly as they work now? And how to make test case #5 work?

Comment: Given your types, someone can call `renderListItem<string>({onClick: id => id.charAt(0)})`, so it is not safe to pass `id` to `onClick()` without checking it first. If you do check, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOG3Rw), then you don't need a type assertion. If you want to actually prevent someone calling the function that way, then you can refactor... but such refactorings will be somewhat annoying to use (and probably more cumbersome/unsafe than a single type assertion).  If that fully addresses your question I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Oh, you are right! My code doesn't works as expected, this code: `renderListItem<string>({onClick: id => id.charAt(0)})` should throw an error "Property 'id' is missing in type...".

Hmmm, looks like it's not that easy to handle that in a way how I would like to see it...

Comment: @avasuro You've marked `id` as optional, so it can be missing.  I think you meant `id: ID`, which requires `id` to be specified but can be assigned `undefined`.

Comment: Also you mention test case #5 which is not included

Comment: @avasuro as I said, the refactoring necessary here would be more annoying and no more type safe than what either `onClick(id as ID)` or `if (id) onClick(id)`.  The *general* issue here is [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) but the approach that normally works, at [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) doesn't help because of the sometimes-optional nature of `id`.  I'm not inclined to go through the exercise of showing exactly how bad it would be.  So do you want me to write up an answer as I asked in my last comment?  Or not?

Comment: @DaveMeehan id should be optional (if it is not provided - 'undefined' should be passed to onClick). About test case #5 - fixed, thank you :)

Comment: @jcalzthe links you've provided helped a lot to understand what is going on here. I think you're fully answered my question, please write up an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

'ID' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | number | undefined', thus, it always has to have a value for one of these types

```
 onClick(id!);
```

And the (!) symbol indicates that (id) will always be one of its defined types